# How many mailgirls were there on Monstervision?

Tags: character, monstervision

On the 90's show TNT's [MonsterVision](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0158420/) with Joe Bob Briggs, how many mail girls were there? I've seen two, [Rusty](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0921779/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1) and the blonde one, but I'm not even sure of her name.

I believe the blonde was in a cheesy movie (*Ultimate Warrior* maybe?) that was later screened on *MonsterVision*, but I can't find the movie in my collection at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to its Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonsterVision#Joe_Bob_Briggs_Era_(1996-2000)), at least four mail girls were seen in the show

> Briggs was also frequently visited by one of a succession of 'mail girls', including **Honey** (Honey Michelle Gregory), **Reno**, **Summer** (Kathy Shower), and **Rusty** (Renner St. John), who not only served as attractive, comedic 'sidekicks,' but also brought Briggs fan letters, sometimes from actual prisoners.

Not sure about the movie you mentioned, but Kathy Shower has more credits on IMDB than the other mail girls.

Comment: Just to mention it, Diana Prince (Darcy the Mailgirl) makes #5 as of "The Last Drive-In" Shudder series, which is technically not Monstervision but hey...